# mvvm universal app why it do not pending

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app

my model inside the shared project

```
class model
{
   public string title;
   public string link;
   public string pubDate;
   public string description;
   public string imageLink;
}
```

and my viewmodel inside the shared project

`class viewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection _posts { get; set; }

```
    public ObservableCollection<model> posts {
        get {
           return _posts ;
        }
        set
        {
            _posts = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("posts");
        }
    }


    public viewModel()
    {
        posts = new ObservableCollection<model>
        {
            new model { title="tiltle", description="description", link="link1" },
            new model { title="tiltle2", description="description2", link="link1" },
            new model { title="tiltle3", description="description3", link="link1" },
            new model { title="tiltle4", description="description4", link="link1" },
            new model { title="tiltle5", description="description5", link="link1" },
        };

    }

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}`
```

my xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=title}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=description}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

my xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new viewModel();
       listBoxControl.DataContext = new viewModel().posts;

    }
```

this is my first question i i have problem with implement mvvm . however i have good understand about it 
when i run i did not see any thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine except you should use properties with getters in your `model` then you will see something.

so:

```
class model
{
   public string title {get;set;}
   public string link  {get;set;}
   //etc..
}
```

because data binding works with Properties not fields.

**on a side note:**
you do not need to name your `ListBox` or set its `DataContext` from code behind, you already did set the `DataContext` of your View to your `ViewModel`, so you can just bind to your ItemsSouce directly such as:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding posts}">
```

even though the way you did it would work just fine.

also don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `model` if the property values change after initalization.

Comment: it work , i do not know how to thank you ,
it is my first question here